# Changing colour of first JButton until second one has been clicked

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonsActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private JButton firstButton;
    private JButton secondButton;


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (firstClick == null) {
            firstClick = (JButton) e.getSource();
        } else {
            secondClick = (JButton) e.getSource();
            // Do something 
            firstClick = null;
            secondClick = null;
    }
}

}
```

This class records the first two JButtons the user has clicked. firstButton represents the first button the user has clicked and secondButton represents the second button the user has clicked.

I want that when the user clicks the first JButton its colour should change to red UNTIL the second JButton has been clicked. Once the second JButton has been clicked I want the first JButton's colour to change back to the original one.

Is there anyway to do this with my current implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve your current implementation, try something like this

```
class ButtonsActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private JButton firstButton;
    private JButton secondButton;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (firstButton == null) {
            firstButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
            firstButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
        } else {
            if (firstButton == (JButton) e.getSource()) {
                firstButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
            } else {
                secondButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
                firstButton.setBackground(null);// reset to original color                    
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Should I set firstButton and secondButton to null after?

Comment: @JackKong That depends on your requirement, do u need to clear button references after changing the color ?

Comment: After I get the first and second button, I need to call a move function that does something based on which two buttons were clicked.

Comment: If you look at my original code, the part where I write "do something", over there I call my move function.

Comment: @JackKong if you do that , resetting the secondButton  background to original color will not work . because  `if (secondButton != null)`  will never be true

Comment: @JackKong I think you want to set the background color to null to achieve the default color

Comment: @aKilleR the code you provided works but the only problem is that the second JButton changes colour to red. I only want that the first one changes colour to red and then once the second button is clicked, the first one goes back to original colour. The colour of the second button should be unaffected. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: @JackKong remove this line secondButton.setBackground(Color.RED);

Comment: @aKilleR you should edit your answer and give the updated one. don't include the code in comment section

Comment: @aKilleR If the user clicks the same button twice, this code doesn't consider that case. Is there anyway to change the code so that it works even if the user clicks the same button twice?

Comment: @JackKong then check `firstButton.getBackground() == Color.RED` and reset the color

Comment: I want that the first and second button should refer to the same button if the user clicks the same button twice.

Comment: simply use   `secondButton = firstButton;` when this `if (firstButton == (JButton) e.getSource())` becomes `true`

Comment: Could you please make these changes in your code above? I will for sure accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background color to default once the second button is clicked. Initially when first button is clicked the color changes to red if second button is clicked the first button color changes back to the default color.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
        final JButton button2 = new JButton("Add");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                button.setBackground(Color.RED);

            }
        });
        button2.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                button.setBackground(null);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To identify which button was clicked, and respond accordingly, you could do:

```
class ButtonsActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (((JButton) e.getSource()) == firstButton) {
                firstButtonClicked();
            } else if (((JButton) e.getSource()) == secondButton) {
                secondButtonClicked();
           }
    }

    private void firstButtonClicked(){
        System.out.println("1st button clicked ");
        //handle second button color 
    }
    private void secondButtonClicked(){
        System.out.println("2nd button clicked ");
        //handle second button color 
    }   
}
```